# How can I generate Aggregate Report. jtl and ResultsTable.csv by executing the existing JMeter script via Taurus

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

I know we have to run the command bzt xxxx.jmx  to execute the existing JMeter script via Taurus and after few mins we will see the nice dashboard.
My question is after the test execution completed how can I generate and view  the AggregateReport.jtl and ResultsTable.csv. We are using these 2 for our analysis and report.

How do I achieve this?
Please advise me!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Rajani

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After test execution Taurus generates some artifacts including normal JMeter `.jtl` results file.

1. Open JMeter GUI. You can do it by appending `-gui` postfix to your Taurus execution command like:

   ```
   bzt yourtest.yaml -gui
   ```
2. Add [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) Listener to your Test Plan
3. Click "Browse" button and locate `kpi.jtl` file inside Taurus artifacts folder.

References:

- [Taurus JMeter Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Executor)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: I have executed my 1st test for the existing script, but I have noticed the following and were not able to see what we expected. I have attached  the screenshots to the original post . But 1.Dashboad didn't give the info at all  2.In artifacts folder i couldnot find the kpi-1.jtl 3.Where do i need to configure to get ResultsTable.csv 4.Basically i am expecting same AgreegateReport. jtl & ResultsTable.csv with the fields i got from when i executed from the JMeter(see the attached xls files). Please advise me where am i missing!